# Java gui - JLabel Location

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I am new here and i want to ask, i just wanted to set new JLabel and i want it to put it to specific place. But it doesnt work. Im sorry if this is dumm question but i am begginer
:

```
package ChangingImageAtTheTop;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Gui {
public static void main(String[] args) {

guii f = new guii();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(500, 500);
f.setVisible(true);

}
} 




package ChangingImageAtTheTop;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class guii extends JFrame {

    public guii() {
        super("c");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
    
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("User");
        label.setBounds(10,25,30,85);
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You don't use a "specific place" with some random size. Instead you use requirements, like centered horizontally (or vertically). At the top/left, or maybe botton/right of the frame. Then you use the appropriate layout manager to achieve this layout. Since you have given a proper requirement we can't provide an appropriate solution. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. Keep a link to the entire tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: oh, thanks, i would like to set the text "User"  to 
coordinates 10,25 but it showed me the deffault position in window

Comment: No, setting the label to (10, 25) is not a requirement. It is two random numbers. Why are those numbers special. What about other components you add to the frame. I doubt you will only have a label. All the components need to work together.  What if the width of the frame is 50 will that make sense? What if the user resizes the frame to 500, will that make sense.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the (entire view of the) GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.